# When using salt-run virt.init, how can I specify initial login credentials for the new guest?

Tags: salt-stack

I'm deploying virtual guests this way:

```
salt-run virt.init vmtest 2 2048 salt://images/ubuntu-image.qcow2
```

It only partially works; `vmtest` is created and its key is added to the master, but the new minion never connects. So I pull up the vnc interface (which works fine) to see what's going on from the minion end, and...can't log in, because I don't know what credentials to use. Oops.

How do I specify initial login credentials when creating a VM with virt.init?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this may not be exactly what you were looking for, but you can use libguestfs-tools in order to set a password on the image itself.

In salt, you can use cmd.run or pass it in a state to change the password after you **install libguestfs-tools** like so:

```
salt 'hypervisor' cmd.run "virt-sysprep --root-password password:'myrootpassword' -a /path/to/image.img"
```

or

```
update_pass:
  cmd.run:
    - name: virt-sysprep --root-password password:'myrootpassword' -a /path/to/image.img
```

Side note:

If you create or update the image you use to spawn new vms to pre-install salt, and update the /etc/salt/minion conf to set your master, and set it to come up at your desired run level, you should be able to work out a solution where the minion connects on creation.

Good luck, I hope this helps.